# Getting react-widgets' elements to align in row-wise flexbox

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox, styling

I'm having trouble integrating [react-widgets](http://jquense.github.io/react-widgets/docs/) (Dropdownlist and Multiselect) with my styling in the same way as the input-fields I've used before.

It should look like this:

[image]

With the white rectangles beeing react-widgets *Dropdownlists* respectively *Multiselect*.

Here's a codepen-example, with the second blue block containing react-widget's markup: http://codepen.io/peletiah/pen/ORLaGr

This is the relevant (simplified) markup:

```css
.route {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.sequence {
  display: flex;
  height: 90px;
  line-height: 90px;
}

.action {
  align-self: center;
  line-height: normal
}
```

```html
<div class="route">
  <div class="sequence">
    <div class="action">
      <span>
            <input value="set">
          </span>
      <span>
            <input value="data goes here">
          </span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="sequence">
    <div class="action">
      <div class="rw-dropdownlist rw-widget">
        <div class="rw-input">set</div>
      </div>
      <div class="rw-multiselect rw-widget">
        <div class="rw-multiselect-wrapper">
          <input>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The markup inside the *action*-div in the second "sequence" is produced by react-widget, so I have a no influence and can't easily replace them with *span*s.

The widgets are supposed to be aligned next to each other like the inputs in the first *sequence*, but they are stacked on top of each other.

Is it possible to fix this with css?

In the codepen-example above I've included the [react-widgets less-code](https://github.com/jquense/react-widgets/tree/master/lib/less) in the upper part of the css-section of the codepend, at then end of it is my custom css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There where two issues with the original code-sample.
Vertical alignment of the "action"-container inside the "sequence"-container was achieved by setting "line-height". 
The line-height is also responsible for the 90px-high "rw-multiselect-wrapper"-div, which it inherits from the "sequence"-class.

Flexbox allows self-alignment of children with the "align-self"-property.

Adding an "align-self" to the class and wrapping each react-widget-div's in their own "action"-div fixes the alignment issue and the height-issue.

```css
.route {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.sequence {
  display: flex;
}

.action {
  align-self: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="route">
  <div class="sequence">
    <div class="action">
      <span>
            <input value="set">
          </span>
    </div>

    <div class="action">
      <span>
            <input value="data goes here">
          </span>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="sequence">
    <span class="sequence-order">2</span>

    <div class="action">
      <div class="rw-dropdownlist rw-widget">
        <div class="rw-input">bridge</div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="action">
      <div class="rw-multiselect rw-widget">
        <div class="rw-multiselect-wrapper">
          test
          <input>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Codepen-sample: http://codepen.io/peletiah/pen/ozjNpW